# How to loop the whole python script for the list

Tags: python

I have a python script example.py, at the end of the script I am generating a list where I get the output like this:

```
[{'name': 'spew', 'version': 'v1.1.0'}
{'name': 'jpath', 'version': 'v0.4.0'}
{'name': 'xddf', 'version': 'v1.5.1'}]
```

How can I run or loop the same script for the above list where it needs to pick the name and the version as input?

Trying with subprocess call
for i in dependencyList:
print(i)
subprocess.call(['python3', 'path of the script', '--user', '--password', '--another-user', '--another-token'])

Comment: you should provide the code of `example.py` and details of the input if needed

Comment: Why can't you save to file the output list of `example.py' and then read it again from another script? Can you please provide us with more information about your use case?

Comment: ```next(i for i in list_of_dicts if i['name'] == 'spew' and i['version'] == 'v1.1.0')``` or ```next(filter(lambda i: i['name'] == 'spew' and i['version'] == 'v1.1.0', list_of_dicts))```

Comment: @mattiatantardini
I am saving the output in the list and trying to run the script for whole list by using subprocess.call but its not working.

Comment: @VladimirVilimaitis the list will not have same output always , so hardcoding name and version not working

Comment: ```(lambda name, version, list_of_dicts: next(i for i in list_of_dicts if i['name'] == name and i['version'] == version))(name_variable, version_variable, particular_list_of_dicts)```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
mydict =[]
for i in range(2):
   name = str(input())
   version = str(input())
   mydict.append({'name':name,'version':version})

for item in mydict:print(item)
```

the result is two dictionary with input you entered